# what safearraygetdata function takes a safearray as input parameter in Delphi instead of vararray

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Programming in Delphi (in xe2) I have a procedure in a dll that returns a `pSafeArray`
I know that it should point to an array of double
to retrieve an element i cannot use `safearraygetelement()`, because it uses a `VarArray` as input parameter.  That would result in a **incompatible-types-compiler-error**.
What is the proper way to get elements?

Answer (score 5):

The `SafeArrayGetElement` function is defined in the `ActiveX` unit as

```
function SafeArrayGetElement(psa: PSafeArray; const rgIndices; out pv): HResult; stdcall;
```

So you can use this function with a PSafeArray. Try this sample

```
var
  LArray: PSafeArray;
  rgIndices, LBound, HBound : Integer;
  DoubleValue: Double;
begin
  //LArray:=.....
  SafeArrayGetLBound(LArray, 1, LBound);
  SafeArrayGetUBound(LArray, 1, HBound);
  for rgIndices := LBound to HBound do
  begin
    SafeArrayGetElement(LArray, rgIndices, DoubleValue);
     // do something
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks,winapi.activex.SafeArrayGetElement works, but the default used by the compiler was Varutils.SafeArrayGetElement. That was my problem.